# Better stylistic choice for "triggered"?

Tags: word-choice, culture

In a [conversation on Quora](https://www.quora.com/qemail/track_click?aoid=XqymyA82z5j&aoty=16&aty=4&click_pos=0&ct=1584822762279433&et=103&force_notif_url&id=9f9d5a4ac05c4beeb22496cdee08ac0a&notif_url=%2FIs-it-possible-to-be-kicked-out-of-a-job-interview%2Fall_comments%2FKonrad-Viltersten%3Fcomment_id%3D132723549%26comment_type%3D2&request_id=5&src=1&st=1584822762290302&stories=7270396942&uid=zaZ8CS4Bjbi&v=0) I used the following expression.

> I don’t feel that you’re getting my point and I start to worry you got **triggered**, possibly recognizing own conduct, hence getting defensive. That said, I reply once again, providing you the benefit of doubt.

On that, someone remarked that the usage of the term *triggered* implies in certain cultural contexts that I'm an extremist and an intolerant kind. According to the person, my wording bears the resemblance of the type of rhetoric that's used by right-wing trolls thriving on causing good people loose their shit and go bananas.

The person's clear that they don't suspect me of being such a pathetic idiot, let alone accusing me of that. Truthfully so, as I'm sometimes crude but always respectful. So, I'm definitely making effort to alter the original wording to better correspond to the message I'm trying to convey.

NB. The formulation is supposed to be harsh, showing that I'm provoked by the original poster's nagging and lack of respect for me not being ready to provide certain information. So the aim isn't to find a more polite formulation. Rather, to find an equally rude one but without the cultural implication of being a *right-wing twittering asshole* (quote from the person who made the remark).

**edit**

Based on the interesting finding in the comments, I realize that I need to clarify the term we're looking for. It's supposed to contain the element of **harsh** and, if possible, not be interpretable as **offending**. And in case it's not feasible, I'd prefer a term that is guaranteed to be **not offending** even if it takes it toll on being **harsh**. So, make it non-offensive primarily and then, harshify it as far as possible under that ceiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question! Finding the right expression in this case seems a little difficult because you want to be "always respectful" and yet "harsh".

The meaning of "triggered" in *this* context is rooted in the modern political usage of the word. And that is why I shall quote the Urban Dictionary (so one can compare it with the alternatives below):

> (popular and well known definition) triggered is when someone gets offended or gets their feelings hurt

That's very straightforward. There may be a few alternatives that can convey that meaning (without having the cultural implication or any political tone to it). However, you also have to think if your adversary will be able to understand the alternatives. If they don't understand your expression or words, they won't be affected in the way you want them to be. You want to be *harsh*, and you want them to feel it.

Do any of these work for you (of course, you will have to adjust the wording surrounding them)?

1. Easily offended
2. [Thin-skinned](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thin-skinned) (easily hurt by criticism or easily made unhappy)
3. [Irascible](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irascible) (made angry easily)
4. [Petulant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/petulant?topic=bad-tempered) (easily annoyed and complaining in a rude way like a child) [needs to be put into context; does not originally state "being offended"; however, it surely implies "being hurt"]
5. [Choleric](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/choleric) (very angry or easily annoyed)
6. [Hysterical](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hysterical?topic=becoming-too-excited-and-easily-upset) (unable to control your feelings or behaviour because you are extremely frightened, angry, excited, etc.) [This could be used like "Relax, (or Calm down,) you're getting hysterical" if it is very clear that your adversary is angry and "triggered"]
7. [Squeamish](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/squeamish?topic=becoming-too-excited-and-easily-upset) (easily upset or shocked by things that you find unpleasant or that you do not approve of)
8. [Fractious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fractious) (easily upset or annoyed, and often complaining)
9. [Huffy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/huffy) (angry and offended)
10. The top voted answer in this ELU post [Word or expression for an opinionated and easily offended person](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173615/word-or-expression-for-an-opinionated-and-easily-offended-person) suggests [someone can dish it out but he or she can’t take it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/someone-can-dish-it-out-but-he-or-she-can-t-take-it).
11. [Sensitive Sally](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sensitive%20sally) from Urban Dictionary:

> (Definition 2) An emotional male, usually conforming to a metrosexual lifestyle or similar. Very in-touch with their feminine side and feelings, usually seen sporting all the latest fashion trends.
>
> They don't seem to appreciate nor understand trolls, and instead resort to name calling and a response of "nah". Even a slight joke at their expense results in a tantrum, followed by a rage quit. Their inability to get a joke, is usually compounded by their scarf wearing antics.
>
> Most tantrums are ended by a storm off, a commanding flick of their scarf, followed by "good day sir"
>
> (Definition 3) A person who is extremely fragile and easy to offend.

12. Fragile Ego (?)
13. **[Snowflake](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snowflake)** (an insulting way of referring to someone who is considered by some people to be too easily upset and offended). Also see the [definitions](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Snowflake) in Urban Dictionary.

---

Edit:

A comment below states

> *"Anyway, irascible and choleric are such thesaurus words, and no one ever actually uses these"*.

This isn't true. A simple google-news search shows their usage. It could be that these words are not often used while speaking, but that is not the same thing as saying *"no one ever actually uses these"*. If that was true, I would expect Cambridge, Collins, and Merriam-Webster to put "archaic" beside them. They haven't done that. I will just list some examples for "irascible" from some reputable sources:

1. *Sanders, an **irascible** Northeastern liberal, was never a natural fit with many black voters ...* - [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/insiders-recount-how-sanders-lost-the-black-vote--and-the-nomination-slipped-away/2020/03/24/2b7b8b8e-685e-11ea-b313-df458622c2cc_story.html), March 25, 2020.
2. *It was also Trump at his most defensive and **irascible**.* - [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/trump-takes-direct-aim-at-china-as-known-us-infections-double-and-criticism-mounts/2020/03/19/6df10828-6a06-11ea-abef-020f086a3fab_story.html), March 19, 2020.
3. *Nick Nolte is the **irascible** Western University coach based ...* - [USA Today](https://www.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/movies/2020/03/09/march-madness-best-basketball-movies-ranked-even-the-way-back/4981841002/), March 9, 2020.
4. *Trump never pivots to maturity and never meets the occasion; he only exhibits **irascible** consistency.* - [NBC News](https://www.nbcnews.com/think/opinion/trump-s-pivots-coronavirus-are-no-longer-just-dizzying-now-ncna1167621), March 24, 2020.
5. *On the other, Sanders, an irascible firebrand, a self-described “Democratic socialist,” ...* - [The Star Vancouver](https://www.thestar.com/opinion/editorials/2020/03/04/the-tug-of-war-for-the-soul-of-the-democratic-party.html), March 4, 2020.
6. *The candidate never lost consciousness and never stopped being his **irascible** self.* - [The Washington Post Magazine](https://www.washingtonpost.com/magazine/2020/03/23/demise-bernie-sanders-wasnt-only-about-ideology-or-policy-it-was-also-about-candidate-himself/?arc404=true), March 23, 2020.
7. ***Irascible***, but mostly composed, ... - [The Nation](https://www.thenation.com/article/politics/bernie-sanders-debate-south-carolina/), Feb 26, 2020.
8. ***Irascible***, uncompromising and ... - [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2020/mar/14/tv-tonight-bebop-racism-and-violence-in-the-life-of-miles-davis), March 14, 2020.
9. *Martin Brest’s 1988 buddy comedy, starring Robert De Niro as an **irascible** bounty hunter ...* - [The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2020/03/covid19-coronavirus-social-distancing-netflix-hulu/608398/), March 20, 2020.
10. *John McEnroe in his prime and at his most **irascible** makes fascinating viewing.* - [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/blog/2019/may/19/john-mcenroe-prime-irascible-realm-of-perfection), May 19, 2019.
11. *On the air, he was an **irascible**, confrontational growler who led pranks and parodies* - [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/12/27/arts/don-imus-dead.html), Dec 27, 2019.
12. *The leaders of the major economies tiptoed around the **irascible** and unpredictable American president.* - [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/26/opinion/g7-summit-amazon.html), Aug 26, 2019.

Comment: *Snowflake* is pretty much in the same league as *triggered*, although I think the characterization provided by the asker-seeker needs verifying: while the word is certainly evocative of the described sort of person, it's hardly confined to it, especially in a context like in that linked comment thread. I guess I just don't see it. Anyway, *irascible* and *choleric* are such thesaurus words, and no one ever actually uses these. They'll just make people (learners of English) feel bad about not knowing them, and they'll unfortunately be added to an already miles-long word list.

Comment: @userr2684291 *Snowflake* has more wide applicability than "triggered". Cambridge lists *snowflake* with the given meaning (which says it can be used without having any political sense to it). Cambridge does not list *triggered* in the sense of the meaning it is used now. My take on this is that *triggered* is more narrowly defined than *snowflake* - *triggered* always has a sense of political or cultural sense to it, but *snowflake* doesn't have that connotation all the time.

Comment: @userr2684291 And it's interesting to hear you say that no one actually uses "irascible" and "choleric". I have seen many uses of them. I have listed a few in the answer. Do you have a source that says those words are archaic or out of use? If not, then your comment is misleading.

Comment: Clearly, people use these words, but they can be a bit sesquipedalian. :)

Comment: @BobRodes You had to look it up, admit it!   :)

Comment: @AIQ All the suggested terms are a bit derogatory, if to different extent. I was aiming at a word describing *catching sufficiently much attention to call for reaction* but definitely not in terms of frowning upon it nor criticizing it in any way. Something like *I confirm the negative sensation I see you've encountered and understanding your perception of what I said, respectfully dismiss that interpretation as not correct in the context of my statement*. So, yeah, I see you reacted and it's fine but not relevant to what's on the table. You're free to have an opinion but it's my statement.

Comment: @AIQ Of course when I said *no one actually uses these words* I meant in actuality, in speech (or informal writing), by people who aren't deliberately going for humorous or pompous verbiage. Looking at the LDOCE and Oxford learner's dictionaries entries, the words are labeled as *formal* / *written*, *literary*, which should be enough to disqualify them as something you'd expect to hear used seriously. I disagree with your other claim about *snowflake*. The word is quite popular in exactly the described contexts, and hence intrinsically intertwined/associated with them.

Comment: I would agree that "snowflake" is, if anything, much worse than "triggered", because "triggered" does potentially have some non-offensive, non-political meanings, but "snowflake" is pretty much only ever used as a (fairly personal) insult, and in the US has come to be used a lot by the "alt right", etc, as well. Also, while "irascible" and "choleric" are occasionally used, they are uncommon enough that I suspect a great many people would not know what they mean without looking them up in a dictionary, which, at best, will harm clarity, and at worst might make you seem pompous or condescending.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Well, yes, I did. I came across the word back in 2017 when I was writing a guide for the writers on the site where I'm an editor, and had to look it up. In that guide, one of the items in the "General Style Considerations" section reads "Work to say what you are saying as simply as possible. (Avoid pleonastic, prolix sesquipedalianism.) " So ha, ha. I admit I had to look it up, but not when I used it this time. :P~~~

Comment: @KonradViltersten Sure, they can be derogatory. Had you mentioned the parts in italics (from your comment) in your original post, I would have suggested something more neutral (again which is difficult in this case given you want to be harsh). I am not sure what you really mean by *"So, yeah, I see you reacted and it's fine but not relevant to what's on the table. You're free to have an opinion but it's my statement."* What do you mean by "reacted"? Are you referring to my answer to your question or my comment to userr? If it is the latter, then my reaction is aimed at (cont.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten ... userr's statement *"no one ever actually uses these"* (whether the suggested words are appropriate for your situation is not relevant to my reply to userr's statement). And what do you mean by "it's my statement"? I don't get it. Are you saying you believe *"no one ever actually uses these"*? If my answer is not helpful, feel free to downvote it. I apologize for not understanding you wanted neutral words.

Comment: @Foogod Okay, yes you are right *snowflake* seems to be more offensive than *triggered*. However, "snowflake" in the dictionaries is just an insult (without any political connotation), and "triggered" does not exist in the dictionaries with the meaning that is being used here (i.e., with the political meaning). You can call someone a *snowflake* without it having any political implication/meaning (as per dictionaries). However, you can't use "triggered" in the context OP did without it having any political meaning. Having said all that, I agree with you on this - *snowflake* is indeed (cont.)

Comment: @Foogod more offensive (and carries more political implication) than "triggered". Now, about the other two words, I don't quite understand why you are telling me that. In my edit (to the answer) I did mention they are not commonly used in speech. *"uncommon enough"* does not mean *"no one ever actually uses these"*. That is the statement I was arguing against. It is misleading and not backed up by any authoritative sources. Also, the asker does not state in their original post that they don't want to use such words. To me these words are harsh - which is what OP asked for.

Comment: @Foogod Whether people have to look them up in a dictionary or whether the user will come across pompous and condescending are issues not mentioned in the original post (and hence not directly relevant to the question). Even so, if you read my answer, you will see that I wrote *"However, you also have to think if your adversary will be able to understand the alternatives."*

Comment: @BobRodes I stand corrected. How could I've missed such an obvious and commonly occurring set of circumstances. One should've see that coming... Pathological example but still valid. And also, now you can say  you've used *sesquipedalianism* at multiple occasions. Between two and three hundreds of times. And as this comment gets posted, you can also refer to other people using it, too! Google trend graph spiking on that term today!

Comment: @AIQ Your answer is great, no objections there. The comment was meant to elaborate on what I try to convey to the poster at Quora. And yes, I realize the difficulty at finding a proper term. It seems that there's a linguistic correlation between *one acknowledging someones negative perception as reasonable* and *one admitting that it's the most accurate interpretation*. I want to express that I respect and understand your raised eyebrows without the need to alter my statement.

Comment: @AIQ Just to clarify, because I see that it's important to you to provide answers of quality - I find your post awesome and informative. I did indeed prefer a neutral term but, apparently, wasn't sufficiently clear on that. It's on me, not you. Also, as with any replies, even if you miss the target, the answer can still be great source of knowledge (i.e. how not to use the words) and broadening the vocabulary. So worry not, mate. I actually upvoted your answer. My apologies if my comment's come across as criticizing or condemning. No such intention what so ever.

Comment: @Foogod See the edit, please.

Comment: @AIQ See the edit - I think I see where I was poorly informative on my intentions. I just got it now.

Comment: Also, both the accepted mark and awarded bounty should be clear on my appreciations of your contribution. Still, see the edit to check if you have some thoughts on that.

Comment: @KonradViltersten All in good fun, sir. :)

Answer (score 1):

I read the conversation linked in the question. This is part of the [comment](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-be-kicked-out-of-a-job-interview/answer/Konrad-Viltersten/comment/132723549) that you are responding to:

> hopefully its a culture gap thing but you should reconsider that usage
>   if youre talking to people in North America

Since the writer's profile is not filled out, it is not possible to know their place of residency with certainty. However, I know my own: I live in Ontario, Canada, which is very much a part of North America, and I am used to hearing the word "triggered" used as it is in the mental health field. Having done a lot of reading in mental health, as well as taken some formal university courses, I understand "triggered" in the mental health field to mean that a certain word or incident sent off a strong emotional reaction inside the psyche, and that this manifested in unwanted feelings and/or behaviour, or both.

The only other applicable word I can think of for the situation you describe is "offended." But we don't like being accused of being offended. Somehow, it makes us feel like we are being called weak or coward or even immoral. Then again, maybe that, too, depends on cultural interpretation. If so, there may not be a word to accomplish your purpose that is totally neutral in all cultures around the world.

Having myself been on Quora a good three years, I think I am familiar with Quora's culture. I think your usage of the word "triggered" fits my definition above. Anyone can be triggered by a word or tone of voice they automatically (and often unconsciously) associate with something unpleasant. In my opinion, it is not necessarily such a bad reflection on your character as the commentator suggests. Thus, I say the writer of that comment is wrong; "triggered" is an appropriate word to use for the situation you describe.

Comment: Hehe, I like the depth of your research of the persona. I usually only see at what's being said here and now. What's been said before might be irrelevant. People change their their attitudes, mature and improve. And can have the account snatched or abused. That being said, I'm not American at all but I still do understand not to call folks in South US for Yankees, so he might have understanding of culture without being a part of it. He also might not, of course. He might be a she or them, too, now that I think about it.

Comment: BTW, the downvote isn't mine. I liked your answer and +1'ed it, in fact.

Comment: Thank you. I have been thinking a couple days about rewriting this answer to better show that who one is is important to my argument. I have now rewritten it. I think it's better.

Comment: Perhaps the person who wrote the original comment on Quora ran across this post, which then triggered a defensive emotional response, which he then acted out by downvoting you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the person who made the remark, but perhaps among younger people than I it is taken this way. In any case, with the idea that simplest is best, perhaps "upset" is a good substitute.

One more thing: we generally *give* the benefit of the doubt rather than *providing* it.

Comment: Two thoughts. If I'd use *upset* (which admittedly is simpler, which is always preferred), I'm afraid that I alter the meaning, although slightly. The way I intended it is to imply that the formulation *caught sufficient (negative) attention to cause a reaction* whereas becoming upset conveys a notion of caused feeling as well, not merely attention. What do you think?

Comment: Second thought - good remark on *giving* instead of *providing*. Possibly it sounds a bit pretentious? Did you get a sense of condemning in that? Or did you just note that it didn't fell naturally expected?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I would say that "negative" implies feeling. One doesn't have purely intellectual positive or negative reactions. The positive and negative reactions come from emotions, ergo feelings. So the idea of negativity devoid of feeling doesn't make sense to me. You might consider "reacted" rather than "got upset."

Comment: Good remark. Didn't think of that.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I'll go just a bit further and share another opinion with you. The idea of "detached negative criticism" that you appear to be attempting to convey doesn't exist in reality. People try to do this sort of thing all the time, and it simply means that they aren't allowing themselves to be aware of the anger they have about whatever they're trying to criticize. Something blunter is more honest, as is the acknowledgement that anger is always a subjective emotion, and therefore "righteous anger" is always "self-righteous anger." (Well, make that two opinions. :) )

Comment: Now that we're bordering the real of philosophy, I wonder if it's possible to argue the non-existence of *detached negative criticism*. Indeed, have I numerous time attempted to express DNC and as far I can analyse my state of mind objectively, I haven't felt said anger. In fact, I've heard the remark that I appear weirdly neutral in front of a aggravating situation, only stating the fact in an almost ominously calm manner. Personally, I see no reason why the "D" would be so difficult to achieve despite giving NC. What do you think about that?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I would be delighted to discuss this further, but I suspect we'll start getting fussed at for having too long of an off-topic conversation. I'll invite you to contact me directly; you can find my particulars at robtrodes at aol. Shoot me an email.